# SQL: Running two queries at once and Assigning Variables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am basically trying to run these two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductTable;

SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
FROM UserTable WHERE id = 41;
```

Both queries work properly. The first one returns me all the data in ProductTable. The second query returns me either `1` or `0` after checking if the row ID 41 exists

**Running them together:**

```
SELECT * FROM ProductTable SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
FROM UserTable WHERE id = 41
```

However, when I run this, the second query does not return any value, **this is because I have not set a SQL variable name to it.**

How can I set a Variable name to the second query such that I can read that value when reading the SQL response?

Comment: What final result you want to have from the query?

Comment: Show your C# code which executes queries an reads results

Comment: The Product Table has 5 Columns, I need to read the second query's data as a column as well. If you know what I mean. So I will be reading 6 columns @Pinwar13

Comment: I ran your query and got the result. It's the same query just the tables are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT *
    ,(
        SELECT CAST(CASE 
                    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END AS BIT)
        FROM UserTable
        WHERE id = 41
        ) AS UserCount
FROM ProductTable;
```

Comment: Good solution! Just to learn about it, can you explain how it works? Is the second query a sub-query?

Comment: Yes its a subquery. Your subquery would run for each and every record in your main query but make sure that your subquery would return only one record.

Comment: You can select the answer that best suits to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the solution & the explanation!

Comment: Since your solution iterates every record in the main query, is there a way to check the id of the record inside the sub query? For example: `inside the sub query -> ...WHERE UserTable.id=MainQuery's currently iterating ID`

Comment: Is there a way to check it inside the sub query?

Comment: You can assign the subquery result to a variable then select your producttable along with the variable. Refer Pinwar13 post.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @val BIT
SELECT @val = CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
FROM UserTable WHERE id = 41

SELECT P.*, @val FROM ProductTable P
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you need  either 1 or 0 after checking if the row ID 41 exists then (following Pinwar13 answer) this code performs better, needn't count all rows

```
DECLARE @val BIT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UserTable WHERE id = 41)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

SELECT P.*, @val FROM ProductTable P
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use cross apply also..

```
SELECT p.*,t.[BIT] FROM ProductTable p
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [BIT])
                FROM UserTable WHERE id = 41)t
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!